# Битрикс. Гугл-карта. Имитировать клик на кластерную метку

Tags: javascript, битрикс, google-maps-api

Есть код вывода гугл-карты:

```
 <?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent(
    "bitrix:map.google.view", 
    "map", 
    array(
        "INIT_MAP_TYPE" => "ROADMAP",
        "MAP_DATA" => serialize(array("google_lat" => $mapLAT, "google_lon" => $mapLON, "google_scale" => 15, "PLACEMARKS" => $arPlacemarks)),
        "MAP_WIDTH" => "100%",
        "MAP_HEIGHT" => "400",
        "CONTROLS" => array(
        ),
        "OPTIONS" => array(
            0 => "ENABLE_DBLCLICK_ZOOM",
            1 => "ENABLE_DRAGGING",
        ),
        "MAP_ID" => "",
        "ZOOM_BLOCK" => array(
            "POSITION" => "right center",
        ),
        "COMPONENT_TEMPLATE" => "map"
    ),
    false
);?>
```

На карте имеется много отмеченных точек, некоторые из них сгруппированы по городам(одна точка на карте и цифра указывающая кол-во меток).
Как имитировать клик по сгруппированной метке на странице, где подключен компонент `bitrix:map.google.view`? Т.е. ниже выводится список городов, нужно чтобы при клике на город(если в нем много меток) увеличивалась карта и отображались все метки этого города. Как такое реализовать?